# Global.asax Application_Error IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError.ExplicitFlush()

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, global-asax

We are seeing the following IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush() exception in our Web Application logs.

What could be the reason and when do we generally get such error?

Appreciate help.

Error:

```
Global.asax:Application_ErrorThe remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070057.
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
at System.Web.Security.CookielessHelperClass.RedirectWithDetection(String redirectPath)
at System.Web.Security.CookielessHelperClass.UseCookieless(HttpContext context, Boolean doRedirect, HttpCookieMode cookieMode)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager.GetCookielessSessionID(HttpContext context, Boolean allowRedirect, Boolean& cookieless)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager.InitializeRequest(HttpContext context, Boolean suppressAutoDetectRedirect, Boolean& supportSessionIDReissue)
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Keep in mind the source is available https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IIS7WorkerRequest.cs,e1ae84221a24533c

Comment: Thanks for the help and also for enlightening me of the fact that IIS source code is available !!